# How can I tell maven where I want the compiled code to go?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Typically all compiled classes go to the target directory. I have a project that wants the compiled classes in a different path. How can I tell Maven to put the compiled classes in a different directory?

Comment: Note that changing the standard values should be avoided if possible. It will confuse people.

Comment: Why does a project needs to be compiled somewhere else? For what purpose?

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to  have a different directory.  This is a 3rd parties source  code.  <shrug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in `pom.xml`

```xml
<build>
    <directory>/path/to/directory</directory>
</build>
```